# Safari Auto-Play Policy default settings

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video

How does Safari determine default Auto-Play Policy? When access website for first time, different settings would appear as default for different websites. For example if you open [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) or [netflix.com](http://netflix.com) default Auto-Play Policy will be *Allow All Auto-Play*, but if you open [bbc.com](http://bbc.com) default Auto-Play Policy will be *Stop Media with Sound*.

Comment: I'm trying to get some information on this as well. :/ Have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: @TomaszCz. Nothing new yet.